# Using external SMTP server on a shared hosting

Tags: shared-hosting

I have a shared hosting account which I use for my small business. Email from my domain always ends up undelivered or at recipients junk mail. Is there any external SMTP service that I could use which can guarantee that my mail is delivered correctly?

Comment: Yes, such services exist.  However, recommending a specific one is not on topic here - see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: Is it possible to have like an example of services?

Answer (score 1):

Your hosted email provider should also provide you with a SMTP server address to use.

Comment: They did. But my email is still getting undelivered because of reasons like "Our system has detected an unusual rate of unsolicited mail originating from your IP address." or it ends up in junk mail. I'm looking for a reliable alternative.

Comment: I would contact your email hosting provider with this info. If they provide you with a SMTP server which ip is on blacklists, it's time to swap email providers.